# Magento 2 get current product id

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

How to fetch the current product id and add in this function?

**Vendor\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product.php**

```
class Product extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity
{
   const PRODUCTID = 'product_id';
   const TABLE_Entity = 'temp_tgs';
   const COL_ENTITY_ID = 'entity_id';

   protected $validColumnNames = [
    self::SKU,
    self::NAME,
];

 protected $_permanentAttributes = [self::SKU];


public function getEntityTypeCode()
{
    return 'my_import';
}


protected function saveAndReplaceEntity()
{
    $behavior = $this->getBehavior();
    $listTitle = [];
    while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
        $entityList = [];
        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                $this->addRowError(ValidatorInterface::ERROR_PRODUCTID_IS_EMPTY, $rowNum);
                continue;
            }
            if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                continue;
            }

            $rowTtile= $rowData[self::PRODUCTID];
            $listTitle[] = $rowTtile;
            $entityList[$rowTtile][] = [
              self::PRODUCTID => $rowData[self::PRODUCTID],
              //self::SKU => $rowData[self::SKU],
            ];
        }
        if (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE == $behavior) {
            if ($listTitle) {
                if ($this->deleteEntityFinish(array_unique(  $listTitle), self::TABLE_Entity)) {
                    $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
                }
            }
        } elseif (\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND == $behavior) {
            $this->saveEntityFinish($entityList, self::TABLE_Entity);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

protected function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData, $table)
{
    if ($entityData) {
        $tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName($table);
        $entityIn = [];
        foreach ($entityData as $id => $entityRows) {
                foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                    $entityIn[] = $row;
                }
        }
        if ($entityIn) {
            $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $entityIn,[
            self::SKU,
            self::COL_ENTITY_ID,   //trying this, but not saving
            //$this->_connection->lastInsertId(),
            ]);
        }
    }
    return $this; 

}
```

Comment: Are you in the product page?

Comment: Im in Import page..i want to insert the product id into my custom table during csv import...But default magento2 csv import file doesnt have product_id it has sku...So i need to get the product ids during import and save them...My custom table has only 1 columm (product_id)

Comment: Pls attach the filename

Comment: Please find the updated code along with saveEntityFinish()

Comment: Isn't $rowData[self::PRODUCTID] ?

Comment: That was static...i used to include product_id as a column in the csv and then import it was saving, now i want to remove the product_id col in csv and while importing only product_ids must be saved to table, based on each SKUs

Comment: Im trying something like this as in the updated code...See saveEntityFinish() for updated code..but its not working

Comment: You cannot do in that way because the entity is not yet created. Try $entityIn[self::PRODUCTID]

Comment: But where is self::PRODUCTID?, i have not included that column in the csv rite? can i just give like that!!

Comment: Is is "product_id" column... don't you have it on your CSV?

Comment: No tats what i was saying...my csv has cols (sku, name, etc) but my table has cols (product_id only), when i import that csv, those products ids must be saved

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$myNewProductId = $this->_connection->lastInsertId();
```

Please try it before putting on production.

Comment: Can u tell where in saveEntityFinish has this to be added? Cause there is one more _connection->getTableName

Comment: Instead of yout $productid=$product->getEntityId();

Comment: This is what im getting systemException
Additional data: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `temp_tgs` (`sku`) VALUES (?), (?), (?), (?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `sku` = VALUES(`sku`), `0` = VALUES(`0`)

Comment: hey @Riccardo..i have updated the entire code here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133777/magento2-get-current-product-id/133794#133794   im getting undefined index error for the entity_id column?

Comment: Any other approach @RiccardoT from the above updated answer!!!..it says undefined 'entity_id'